# Converting NSKeyArchiver from Obj C to Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class that I created in Obj C and archived using the following metod

```
    // encode the history object for saving
NSData *hisotryEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:historyObject];
```

Now I want to unarchive that same class but in a completely different app. I am able to access the array that holds those archived objects, but I'm having difficulty unarchiving them.

In Obj C I used this method

```
// un archive the history array objects
for (NSData *historyData in historyArray)
{
    // set a instance of the person class to each NSData object found in the temp array
    GD_Owed_HistoryObject *historyObject = [[GD_Owed_HistoryObject alloc] init];
    historyObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:historyData];
    NSLog(@"This is the history object %@", historyObject);
    NSLog(@"This is the save date %@", historyObject.saveDate);
    NSLog(@"This is the total before %@", historyObject.beforeTotal);
    NSLog(@"This is the total after %@", historyObject.afterTotal);
    NSLog(@"This is the amount changed %@", historyObject.amountChanged);
    //[decodedHistoryArray addObject: historyObject];

    [decodedHistoryArray insertObject:historyObject atIndex:0];
}
```

I tried to convert that to swift 3

```
let historyArray = NSArray(array:statementHistory, copyItems: true)

    for historyData:NSData in historyArray{

        let historyObject = UserDefaultHistory
        historyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: historyData)
        print("\(historyObject.saveDate)")
    }
```

`historyArray` contains the archived objects from the Obj C app.

I get this error

```
NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') is not convertible to 'NSData'
enter code here
```

**Update**

When I check the objects in the array I get back what I expect.

```
> print("\(type(of: statementHistory)) type of array") // Array<UserDefaultHistory> type of array
```

But when I try to access a property of UserDefaultHistory like this

```
print("\(type(of: statementHistory[0].saveDate)) this is the save date")
```

I get this error

```
    fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
2017-03-02 15:01:59.098064 owed[1535:708223] fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

I'm just at a loss as to what element is in the NSArray if it's not UserDefaultHistory objects.

Comment: What is UserDefaultHistory and why are you setting the object from unarchiveObject to UserDefaultHistory?

Comment: userDefaultHistory is the NSCoding class used to decode the object. My old project it was called  GD_Owed_HistoryObject this project its called userDefaultHistory

Comment: I think all you have to do is to save the result of NSKeyedUnarchiver as data first, specifying a type.

Comment: @El Tomato could you show me what you mean, I'm not sure I follow what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for historyData in historyArray{
    let tempData = historyData as! NSData
    let historyObject = UserDefaultHistory
    historyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: tempData)
    print("\(historyObject.saveDate)")
}
```

Comment: If `historyData` is not `NSData` this line leads to crash runtime - `let tempData = historyData as! NSData`

Comment: wouldn't this make it NSData? `NSData *hisotryEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:historyObject];`